# Codeigniter Model multiple join statement returns last statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a join statement which joins HomeID and AwayID from a team table that has TeamID. When I join the two tables it only returns the values from the last join statement. Here is my model :-

```
function get_fixtures(){
    $where=array(
    'gameweek'=>1,
    );

    $this->db->select();
    $this->db->from('matches AS M');
    $this->db->join('team AS T2', 'T2.teamID=M.awayClubID' );
    $this->db->join('team AS T1', 'T1.teamID=M.homeClubID');
    $this->db->where($where);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

When I print out the result it only returns T1 results. If anyone can help will appreciate :-)

Comment: trying printing the sql using `echo $this->db->last_query();`

Answer (score 0):

You cant return the result array directly

```
 $this->db->select();
            $this->db->from('matches M');
            $this->db->join('team T2', 'T2.teamID=M.awayClubID' );
            $this->db->join('team T1', 'T1.teamID=M.homeClubID');
            $this->db->where($where);
            $query = $this->db->get();

            foreach($query->result_array() as $que)
            {
                  $n[] = $que;
            }
            retunr $n;
```

Comment: `$query->result_array()` returns you an array, not a problem there. The problem is with the join.

Comment: I think @ParagTyagi is right,the problem is with the join statement.do you have an idea of how i will formulate the join statement so that it return both join statements. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: You dont need `as` in codeigniter .Maybe that was the problem. Else your query is correct .

Answer (score 0):

You are using **`2 aliases`** for the same table. Hence don't use alias for `team` table.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('matches AS M');
$this->db->join('team', 'team.teamID=M.awayClubID', 'inner');
$this->db->join('team', 'team.teamID=M.homeClubID', 'inner');
$this->db->where($where);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

**OR** only use it for the second time (temp solution).

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('matches AS M');
$this->db->join('team', 'team.teamID=M.awayClubID', 'inner');
$this->db->join('team as t', 't.teamID=M.homeClubID', 'inner');
$this->db->where($where);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

**EDIT:**

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('matches AS M');
$this->db->join('team as T', 'T.teamID=M.awayClubID OR T.teamID=M.homeClubID', 'inner');
$this->db->where($where);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but i got this error                                   Not unique table/alias: 'team'

SELECT * FROM (`matches` AS M) INNER JOIN `team` ON `team`.`teamID`=`M`.`awayClubID` INNER JOIN `team` ON `team`.`teamID`=`M`.`homeClubID` WHERE `gameweek` = 1

Comment: and temp solution code still returns only M.homeClubID and not M.awayClubID

Comment: check if you get something here: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/76383/#384940

Comment: the post is from 2008 , the bugfix link is not working.but appreciate your help tho :-) will try figure t out...

Comment: Hey @bobin56, I've tried something similar on my local and got the expected result. Kindly try the edited query. What's your solution is sort of a hack but not the exact solution. A simple `join` with an `or` might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,i have figure it out myself by distinguishing the columns in the select statement.Here is the code :-

```
function get_fixtures(){
                $where=array(
                'gameweek'=>1,
                );
                $this->db->select('m.*, T1.clubName T1name,T2.clubName T2name');
                $this->db->from('matches as m');
                $this->db->join('team AS T1', 'T1.teamID=M.homeClubID', 'left');
               $this->db->join('team AS T2', 'T2.teamID=M.awayClubID', 'left');


                $this->db->where($where);
                $query = $this->db->get();
                return $query->result_array();

     }
```